# PHP Nested foreach on multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, nested

The following array gives me multiple "options" (type, purity, model). Keep in mind that "options" may increase or decrease on next iteration of the loop.

```
$options = array(
    'type' => array('Old', 'Latest', 'GOLD 1.0', 'GOLD 1.1', 'GOLD 1.2', 'GOLD 1.3'),
    'purity' => array('GOLD', 'SILVER', 'BRONZE'),
    'model' => array('Rough', 'Neat', 'mixed', 'Random'),
);
```

The output I want to achieve is

```
Old   GOLD  Rough
Old   GOLD  Neat
Old   GOLD  mixed
Old   GOLD  Random

Old   SILVER  Rough
Old   SILVER  Neat
Old   SILVER  mixed
Old   SILVER  Random

Old   BRONZE  Rough
Old   BRONZE  Neat
Old   BRONZE  mixed
Old   BRONZE  Random

Then this whole scenario goes for 'Latest', 'GOLD 1.0', 'GOLD 1.1',
'GOLD 1.2' and 'GOLD 1.3'(each element of first array)

This way it will generate total 72 combinations (6 * 3 * 4)
```

WHAT I HAVE ACHIEVED SO FAR.

If I have static "options" (type, purity, model) I can use nested foreach i.e

```
$type = array('Old', 'Latest', 'GOLD 1.0', 'GOLD 1.1', 'GOLD 1.2', 'GOLD 1.3');
$purity = array('GOLD', 'SILVER', 'BRONZE');
$model = array('Rough', 'Neat', 'mixed', 'Random');

foreach( $type as $base ){
                foreach( $purity as $pure ){
                    foreach( $model as $mdl ){
             echo $base.' '.$pure.' '.$mdl.'<br />';

     }
   }
 }
```

But I don't know how many foreach loops should I use, as "options" may decrease or increase. So I have to dynamically go through the array. Any help will be much appreciated
thanks

Comment: You have 3 arrays, from your example it is not clear how you relate them. They are all different sizes.

Comment: @Muhammed M. 
the options and values are coming from DB 

`$options = array(
    'type' => array('Old', 'Latest', 'GOLD 1.0', 'GOLD 1.1', 'GOLD 1.2', 'GOLD 1.3'),
    'purity' => array('GOLD', 'SILVER', 'BRONZE'),
    'model' => array('Rough', 'Neat', 'mixed', 'Random'),
);`

Lets suppose in the next iteration it might not have 'model' or it might add some other array in `$options` array. so the size of this array might increase or decrease.

I want to achieve the combinations from the data within `$options` array.

Comment: what do you mean if options increase? can you give example? edit your anwer please, we will solve your problem. Right now output is 3 columns, if you add another option output will be 4 columns correct? So basically, number of columns in your output is the size of your options array, correct? output result should be: column1, column2, column3.... column N -> all matched with $options[0], $options[1]...$options[N-1] , correct?

Comment: hmm, ok looks like you soled your problem ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$options = array(
    'type' => array('Old', 'Latest', 'GOLD 1.0', 'GOLD 1.1', 'GOLD 1.2', 'GOLD 1.3'),
    'purity' => array('GOLD', 'SILVER', 'BRONZE'),
    'model' => array('Rough', 'Neat', 'mixed', 'Random'),
);

// Create an array to store the permutations.
$results = array();
foreach ($options as $values) {
    // Loop over the available sets of options.
    if (count($results) == 0) {
        // If this is the first set, the values form our initial results.
        $results = $values;
    } else {
        // Otherwise append each of the values onto each of our existing results.
        $new_results = array();
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $new_results[] = "$result $value";
            }
        }
        $results = $new_results;
    }
}

// Now output the results.
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo "$result<br />";
}
```